# How are the <!DOCTYPE> and <html> tags important for SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, html, doctype

I'd like to compare the two sites:

Site A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en_US>
<head>
```

Site B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
```

The differences are:

1. Site A doesn't have `"` for tag attributes.
2. Site A has a very simple `!DOCTYPE` tag
3. Site A has a very simple `html` tag

I'm wondering, are the three factors important for SEO rankings?

Comment: Outside of lang= defining the language there is no role for any of these tags.

Comment: What do you mean? sorry I don't quite get it.

Comment: SEO is not about tags. It is about content. Short of the lang= in the HTML tag defining the language of the page, these tags have absolutely nothing to do with SEO.

Comment: `Short of the lang= in the HTML tag defining the language of the page` what do you mean by this“short of”? I'm still confused.

Comment: The Doctype stuff that is there tells the browser how to read the HTML. You will typically see strict 1.0 ones used in email, due to emails clients. <!DOCTYPE html> is HTML 5. you can find out more on common doctypes at w3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is if HTML [document type](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) could affect SEO, right?. Based on my experience and logic I'll say no.

A site built to standards (valid HTML and CSS) is often easier to access and crawl by searchers but using different doctype will not boost your ranks cause [accesibility it's not a direct SEO factor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1005&v=tcU1elqTkJQ).

As long as you can check that [Google renders](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) your site correctly (without any error), nothing else in your code -from a tech point of view- should matter.